# How to compare different encoding strings in Python

Tags: python, character-encoding

I need to load two different json files and save it in arrays.

And I convert the 2 arrays into `set A` and `set B`

I want to find the difference in `set A` and `set B`

So I tried `setA ^ set B` ,

But it result is not as my expect.

Actually, The 2 arrays are identical without considering encoding.

So I got  `len(setA ^ set B)`  is > `0` , because their encoding is different.

What is the Python way to covert different encoding strings into the same encoding?

Array A

```
"'Original'", "'Original'", "'Original'", "'Original'", "'Originale'", "u'\u30aa\u30ea\u30b8\u30ca\u30eb'", "'Original'", "u'\u539f\u59cb\u7684'", "u'\u539f\u59cb'", "u'Origin\xe1ln\xed'", "u'\u041d\u043e\u0440\u043c\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043d. \u0432\u0438\u0434'",
```

Array B

```
"'Original'", "'Original'", "'Original'", "'Original'", "'Originale'", "'\xe3\x82\xaa\xe3\x83\xaa\xe3\x82\xb8\xe3\x83\x8a\xe3\x83\xab'", "'Original'", "'\xe5\x8e\x9f\xe5\xa7\x8b\xe7\x9a\x84'", "'\xe5\x8e\x9f\xe5\xa7\x8b'", "'Origin\xc3\xa1ln\xc3\xad'", "'\xd0\x9d\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbd. \xd0\xb2\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb4'",
```

Comment: The two arrays you showed here are obviously **not** identical - not even close.  Perhaps some elements in Array B are encoded, where the corresponding elements in A are Unicode strings?  In that case, you have to know the encoding being used for each string in Array B.  Do you know?

Comment: array A has unicode data and Array B has hex data. Two compare both of them you have to convert them in same format (ascii). You can use `.decode("hex")` to convert from hex to ascii and `.encode('ascii', 'ignore')` for unicode to ascii. Note: There are many other ways for conversion from one format to other.